# R data.table to determine if a person is new or existing

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data.table

```
year      Person     Number_of_visits
2012      1          0
2013      1          4
2014      1          0
2015      1          1
2012      2          1
2013      2          5 
...
```

I would like to determine by each person, which year their first visit is. So a desired output is:

```
year      Person     Number_of_visits    New?
2012      1          0                   NA
2013      1          4                   Yes
2014      1          0                   No
2015      1          1                   No
2012      2          1                   NA
2013      2          5                   No
```

I think one could perhaps use the SHIFT function in data.table, but I can't figure out how to do so. Once a person has had a visit, he/she is not new anymore, even though there may be a year afterwards with no visits. If the first visits occur in 2012, there should be an NA or similar entry.

I have used

```
test <- DT[ , NEW := c(0, (2:1)[(Number_of_visits== shift(Number_of_visits)) + 1][-1]), by = Person]
```

but this naturally gives me all changes, and I would like to only register the first change from 0 to some value above 0 (number of visits)

Comment: Please share your attempts using `data.table`.

Comment: test <- DT[ , NEW := c(0, (2:1)[(Number_of_visits== shift(Number_of_visits)) + 1][-1]), by = Person]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would break this into the following steps (I'm sure the solution could be golfed to something much shorter though)

```
setorder(dt, Person, year) # Make sure the order is correct
dt[, New := "No"] # Set No as default
dt[dt[, .I[which.max(Number_of_visits > 0)], by = Person]$V1, New := "Yes"] # find first visits
dt[year == 2012, New := NA_character_] # Set NAs to 2012
dt
#    year Person Number_of_visits New
# 1: 2012      1                0  NA
# 2: 2013      1                4 Yes
# 3: 2014      1                0  No
# 4: 2015      1                1  No
# 5: 2012      2                1  NA
# 6: 2013      2                5  No
```

Comment: Once again a very good answer from David (and akrun). Thank you very much!